# Non-declaration statement outside function body in Go

Tags: variables, scope, go, package, global

I'm building a Go library for an API that offers JSON or XML formatted data.

This API requires me to request a `session_id` every 15 minutes or so, and use that in calls. For example:

```
foo.com/api/[my-application-id]/getuserprofilejson/[username]/[session-id]
foo.com/api/[my-application-id]/getuserprofilexml/[username]/[session-id]
```

In my Go library, I'm trying to create a variable outside of the `main()` func and intend to ping it for a value for every API call. If that value is nil or empty, request a new session id and so on.

```
package apitest

import (
    "fmt"
)

test := "This is a test."

func main() {
    fmt.Println(test)
    test = "Another value"
    fmt.Println(test)

}
```

What is the idiomatic Go way to declare a globally-accessible variable, but not necesarilly a constant?

My `test` variable needs to:

- Be accessible from anywhere within it's own package.
- Be changeable

Answer (score 116):

You need

```
var test = "This is a test"
```

`:=` only works in functions and the lower case 't' is so that it is only visible to the package (unexported).

A more thorough explanation

**test1.go**

```
package main

import "fmt"

// the variable takes the type of the initializer
var test = "testing"

// you could do: 
// var test string = "testing"
// but that is not idiomatic GO

// Both types of instantiation shown above are supported in
// and outside of functions and function receivers

func main() {
    // Inside a function you can declare the type and then assign the value
    var newVal string
    newVal = "Something Else"

    // just infer the type
    str := "Type can be inferred"

    // To change the value of package level variables
    fmt.Println(test)
    changeTest(newVal)
    fmt.Println(test)
    changeTest(str)
    fmt.Println(test)
}
```

**test2.go**

```
package main

func changeTest(newTest string) {
    test = newTest
}
```

**output**

```
testing
Something Else
Type can be inferred
```

Alternatively, for more complex package initializations or to set up whatever state is required by the package GO provides an init function.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var test map[string]int

func init() {
    test = make(map[string]int)
    test["foo"] = 0
    test["bar"] = 1
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(test) // prints map[foo:0 bar:1]
}
```

Init will be called before main is run.

Comment: If an initializer is present, the type can be omitted; the variable will take the type of the initializer.

Answer (score 37):

If you accidentally use "**Func**" or "**function**" or "**Function**" instead of "**func**" you will also get:

> non-declaration statement outside of function body

Posting this because I initially ended up here on my search to figure out what was wrong.

Comment: or if you typo func, ommitting the space between keyword and function name

Comment: I wrote `void main()` and landed here, did you?

Answer (score 6):

Short variable declarations i.e. `:=`, can **ONLY** be used within functions.

e.g.

```
func main() {
    test := "this is a test"
    // or
    age := 35
}
```

Declarations outside a function you must make use of keywords like `var, func, const` e.t.c depending on what you want *(in this case we're using `var`)*.

Declaring a variable outside a function makes it accessible within its package.

```
package apitest

import (
    "fmt"
)
// note the value can be changed
var test string = "this is a test"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(test)
    test = "Another value"
    fmt.Println(test)

}
```

**Extra info**

If you want the variable to be accessible both within and outside its package, the variable has to be **capitalized** e.g.

```
var Test string = "this is a test"
```

this will make it accessible from any package.

Answer (score 4):

> Outside a function, every statement begins with a keyword (`var`, `func`, and so on) and so the `:=` construct is not available.

You can read more information here: https://tour.golang.org/basics/10

Answer (score 3):

We can declare variables as below:

```
package main

import (
       "fmt"
       "time"
)

var test = "testing"
var currtime = "15:04:05"
var date = "02/01/2006"

func main() {
    t := time.Now()
    date := t.Format("02/01/2006")
    currtime := t.Format("15:04:05")

    fmt.Println(test) //Output: testing
    fmt.Println(currtime)//Output: 16:44:53
    fmt.Println(date) // Output: 29/08/2018
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I was trying to run Go app with function definition like this:

```
(u *UserService) func GetAllUsers() (string, error) {...} //Error code
```

The correct way of defining a function (receiver function) was:

```
func (u *UserService) GetAllUsers() (string, error) {...} //Working code
```