# Create a global bidimensional slice with length taken in input

Tags: go

I need to create a bidimensional slice with a custom length, taken in input. The slice is the field of my minesweeper, so the length will be the dimension of the field.
I need the slice to be global, right now I inizialize the slice directly to the costant dimension of the field, but I am implementing the difficulty, so I need the field to be variable.

```
//my code right now
const dimX int = 16            //X field dimension
const dimY int = 16            //Y field dimension
var bombs int = 40             //number of mines
var number [dimX][dimY]int8    //number contained in the cell, 0 if empty, -1 if mine
var isOpen [dimX][dimY]bool    //if the cell is visible to the user
var isFlagged [dimX][dimY]bool //if the cell is marked as a bomb
```

Is there a way I can declare the variables and then initialize them in a function, something like this (that way is obv not possible in go):

```
//what i'd like to do
var dimX, dimY, bombs int
var number [][]int8
    
func main() {
   Scan(&dimX, &dimY, &bombs)
   number = [dimX][dimY]
   ...
}
```

I tried also something with make, but it gives me an incompatible assign (cannot use make([][]uint8, dimX) (value of type [][]uint8) as [16][16]int8):

```
func main() {
   Scan(&dimX, &dimY, &bombs)
   number = make([][]uint8, dimX)
   for i := range number {
      number[i] = make([]uint8, dimY)
   }
   ...
}
```

The only way I found is viable is via the append() function: declare the field to [][] or [0][0] and after the user input run a function that append() x times and y times to the slice

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Non-declaration statement outside function body in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508356/non-declaration-statement-outside-function-body-in-go)

Comment: @RisingSun no, I know how to declare global and local variables. My question was about initialize a slice inside a function (with a specific length), not a normal variable

Comment: Read through the answers. A slice is a variable

Comment: @RisingSun I read the question you suggested again, I found the solution which is basically the one Cesire Limon answered to this question. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first snippet of code in the question uses an array of arrays.  The length of an [array](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Array_types) is set at compile time.

Use a [slice](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types) of slices as in the second snippet of code. The length of a slice is dynamic.

Allocate the slices with [make](https://pkg.go.dev/builtin#make) as shown in the third snippet of code.

```
var dimX, dimY, bombs int
var number [][]int8  // empty [] is a slice.

fmt.Scan(&dimX, &dimY, &bombs)
number = make([][]int8, dimX)
for i := range number {
    number[i] = make([]int8, dimY)
}
```

Note: The code in the question uses `int8` and `uint8` when referring to the elements. These are different types. This answer uses `int8`.

[Run the example on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/YdZyZixD9M9).