# Golang: accessing map object outside the function it was declared in

Tags: go

I would like to loop through a slice of structs, and populate a struct field (which is a map) by passing in each struct to a function.

I have the below struct

```golang
type thing struct {
    topicThing map[string]int
}
```

and I have the below functions

```golang
func main() {
    ths := make([]thing, 0)
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        var th thing
        ths = append(ths, th)
    }

    for _, th := range ths {
        dothing(&th)
    }

    for _, th := range ths {
        fmt.Println(th.topicThing)
    }
}

func dothing(th *thing) {
    tc := make(map[string]int)
    tc["Hello"] = 1
    tc["Bye"] = 2
    th.topicThing = tc
}
```

The main function creates a slice of things (refered as ths), and passes each thing to the dothing() function by iterating over them.
Within dothing(), I create a new map, populate it with data, and assigns it to the passed in thing's attribute. However, by the time we iterate over ths in the main function to print topicThing of each thing, the map is empty.

Since make() creates objects within the heap, I was hoping it would be accessible even outside of the function scope. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

P.S.
if I change the dothing() function like below:

```golang
func dothing(th *thing) {
    th.topicThing["Hello"] = 1
    th.topicThing["Bye"] = 2
}
```

The code works as expected, meaning the map is populated with data when accessed in the main function.

Comment: „ Since make() creates objects within the heap,“ This is completely wrong.

Comment: @Volker would you mind elaborating or pointing me to an article that explains how memory is allocated?

Comment: Memory is allocated wherever the compiler decides. This is different from compiler to compiler, between versions and architectures. Peek at the disasembly. Formaly Go has just memory, nether heap nor stack.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Non-declaration statement outside function body in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508356/non-declaration-statement-outside-function-body-in-go)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `range` copies your object.
So when you do this,

```golang
    for _, th := range ths {
        dothing(&th)
    }
```

you are actually `dothing` on a copy.

For example, with this `main`:

```golang
func main() {
    ths := make([]thing, 0)
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        var th thing
        ths = append(ths, th)
    }

    for _, th := range ths {
        dothing(&th)
        fmt.Println(th.topicThing)
    }
```

it will print the right thing, since we are still working on the copy.

In order to not copy, use the array index:

```golang
    for idx, _ := range ths {
        dothing(&ths[idx])
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That makes sense. However, that doesn't explain why the second code works.

Comment: The second code works because you are passing a pointer to the real object to `dothing` and not a pointer to a copy. As such the `dothing` will change the intended object.

Comment: If the `range` returns a copy, am I not passing in the address of the copy?

Comment: You are, and as such the modification that you are doing happens on the copy. When the loop finishes, the copy is destroyed.

Comment: @BesDollma: OP means the second version of the code in the question, where `dothing` does `th.topicThing["hello"] = 1`; that works even when working with the copy from `range`.

Comment: @sk311: Your second code works because the copy of `th` contains a copy of `topicThing`, but a map is a reference type, so the copy refers to the same underlying memory that the original did.

Comment: @NickMatteo Thank you for clarifying my questions and providing the answer!!